# Sort Ruby String Array by the number in the string

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, sorting

If I have a string array that looks like this:

> array = ["STRING1", "STRING05", "STRING20", "STRING4", "STRING3"]

or

> array = ["STRING: 1", "STRING: 05", "STRING: 20", "STRING: 4", "STRING: 3"]

How can I sort the array by the number in each string (descending)?

I know that If the array consisted of integers and not strings, I could use:

> sort_by  { |k, v| -k }

I've searched all around but can't come up with a solution

Comment: Please clarify whether the numbers can have more than a single digit.  If 'yes' I suggest you indicate that by simply changing the example to include at least one number greater than 9. If 'no', `array.sort_by(&:reverse).reverse` also works.

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland! I see what you mean, good to know that works.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The below would sort by the number in each string and not the string itself

```
array.sort_by { |x| x[/\d+/].to_i }
=> ["STRING: 1", "STRING: 2", "STRING: 3", "STRING: 4", "STRING: 5"]
```

descending order:

```
array.sort_by { |x| -(x[/\d+/].to_i) }
=> ["STRING: 5", "STRING: 4", "STRING: 3", "STRING: 2", "STRING: 1"]
```

Comment: Remember to convert this to an integer otherwise you'll get unexpected ordering when 1-digit numbers are compared to 2-digit numbers

Comment: bjhaid, it's now hard to choose between your answer and @xdazz's. :-)

Comment: @CarySwoveland well I did provide the answer with the main idea first (4 minutes earlier than xdazz's) and modification came after the comments, it's the concept behind it that really matters, the remaining changes are obvious, you can check my edit history to confirm that

Answer (score 3):

> sort the array by the number in each string (descending)

```
array.sort_by { |x| -x[/\d+/].to_i }
```